# Display last message in chat with firestore

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

How I can get and display **last message** in my **chat**?

For test, I created **four** users with test **messages**. Now I can display only **last message** for all users. I mark **red** color.

Also I use firebase to save **messages** and create **channels**.

Struct in firebase look like this:

```
- Chats 
    - channel id 
        - document data (then be stored ID and NAME of channel)
        - collection thread
            - documents data (then be stored MESSAGES)
```

My struct in **channel**:

```
struct Channel {
    let id: String?
    let name: String

    init(name: String) {
        id = nil
        self.name = name
    }

    init?(document: DocumentSnapshot) {
        let data = document.data()!
        guard let name = data["name"] as? String else {
            return nil
        id = document.documentID
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Channel: DatabaseRepresentation {
    var representation: [String : Any] {
        var rep = ["name": name]
        if let id = id {
            rep["id"] = id
        }
        return rep
    }
}
```

And my struct **message**, I use `MessageKit`:

```
struct Message: MessageType {

let id: String?
let content: String
let sentDate: Date
let sender: SenderType

var kind: MessageKind {
    if let image = image {
        return .photo(ImageMediaItem.init(image: image))
    } else {
        return .text(content)
    }
}

var messageId: String {
    return id ?? UUID().uuidString
}

var image: UIImage? = nil
var downloadURL: URL? = nil

init(profile: Profile, content: String) {
    sender = Sender(id: profile.id, displayName: profile.name)
    self.content = content
    sentDate = Date()
    id = nil
}

init?(document: QueryDocumentSnapshot) {
    let data = document.data()

    guard let sentDate = (data["created"] as? Timestamp)?.dateValue() else { 
        return nil
    }

    guard let senderID = data["senderID"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }
    guard let senderName = data["senderName"] as? String else {
        return nil
    }

    id = document.documentID

    self.sentDate = sentDate
    sender = Sender(id: senderID, displayName: senderName)

    if let content = data["content"] as? String {
        self.content = content
        downloadURL = nil
    } else if let urlString = data["url"] as? String, let url = URL(string: urlString) {
        downloadURL = url
        content = ""
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

}

extension Message: DatabaseRepresentation {

```
var representation: [String : Any] {
    var rep: [String : Any] = [
        "created": sentDate,
        "senderID": sender.senderId,
        "senderName": sender.displayName 
    ]

    if let url = downloadURL {
        rep["url"] = url.absoluteString
    } else {
        rep["content"] = content
    }

    return rep
}
```

}

For load my **chennels** I use code below:

```
fileprivate func observeQuery() {
    guard let query = query else { return }
    listener = query.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
        guard let snapshot = snapshot else {
            print("Error listening for channel updates: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No error")")
            return
        }

        snapshot.documentChanges.forEach { (change) in
            self.handleDocumentChange(change)
        }
    }
}

private func handleDocumentChange(_ change: DocumentChange) {
    guard let channel = Channel(document: change.document) else {
        return
    }
    switch change.type {
    case .added:
        addChannelToTable(channel)
    case .modified:
        updateChannelInTable(channel)
    case .removed:
        removeChannelFromTable(channel)
    }
}

private func addChannelToTable(_ channel: Channel) {
    guard !channels.contains(channel) else {
        return
    }
    channels.append(channel)
    channels.sort()

    guard let index = channels.index(of: channel) else {
        return
    }
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}

private func updateChannelInTable(_ channel: Channel) {
    guard let index = channels.index(of: channel) else {
        return
    }
    channels[index] = channel
    tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}

private func removeChannelFromTable(_ channel: Channel) {
    guard let index = channels.index(of: channel) else {
        return
    }
    channels.remove(at: index)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: [IndexPath(row: index, section: 0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

I think need update my **Channel struct**. But how to do it?

And how to correct load and display **last message** from **firebase**?

If need more info pls tell me, I will update my question.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If the question is how to get only the last message from Firestore, you need to define how to determine what the last message is. That's usually done via a timestamp - the latest timestamp will be the last message.

The structure in the question is a little unclear so let me provide a simple example.

```
messages //collection
   document_0 //documentID auto-generated
      msg: "Last Message"
      timestamp: "20191201"
   document_1
      msg: "First message"
      timestamp: "20190801"
   document_2
      msg: "A message in the middle"
      timestamp: "20191001"
```

As you can see, no matter what order they are written to Firestore, it's clear that the one with the latest timestamp (20191201 ) is the last message.

To get the last message we need a query that does two things:

1) Query the messages node, sort descending, which will put the last message 'at the top'

2) Limit the query to 1, which will get that message.

```
func readLastMessage() {
    let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("messages").order(by: "timestamp", descending: true).limit(to: 1)
    ref.getDocuments(completion: { querySnapshot, error in
        guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
            print("Error fetching snapshots: \(error!)")
            return
        }

        if let doc = snapshot.documents.first {
            let docID = doc.documentID
            let msg = doc.get("msg")
            print(docID, msg)
        }
    })
}
```

and the output

```
Last Message
```

The above code gets the last message but could be expanded upon by adding an observer instead of getDocuments in the same fashion that will notify the app when there's a new last message.

Comment: If I understood correctly then you showed me how to display one for all users?

How to get last messages for my four users and display their?
`1st user - last message1`
`2nd user - last message2`
and etc

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев This code shows how to retrieve the last message from a series of messages based on a timestamp. As mentioned in the answer, the actual structure in the question is a bit unclear so I had to provide example data. If you can clarify what the structure is, I may be able to provide more info - however, the process is the same - you need some way to determine which message is the last message (I suggested a timestamp), query descending and get 1 message, which will be the last.

Comment: My messages stored in collection `chats` inside the collection there is another collection `thread` and in collection `thread` i store messages. `Struct Message` I added in questions.

Comment: maybe it makes sense to add a variable `var messages: Message?` in struct `Channel`? But I don't know how to work with such a structure in the end :(

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев As I mentioned, the actual Firestore structure is unclear so I had to substitute one. If you can update your question with a clear structure we can take a look.

Comment: @ДмитрийДеникаев Did you have a solution and the problem solved? Could you show me?